# Copy data from multiple sheets into multiple sheets in new workbook

Tags: excel, vba, move

I know variations of this question have been asked but I can't seem to find the right code to accomplish this task. I have 2 tabs, Master Summary and Master Detail, from which I would like to copy data based on cell values in columns K and G respectively. I would like to copy data from both tabs into a new workbook if the values where these columns match. Each value needs its own workbook to be saved as the name in the cell.

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Mike S, I'd be surprised if anyone writes the code for you. Try something yourself and let us know exactly where you are struggling.

Comment: My apologies this is my first time using this forum.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with:

Sub CopyCMOsToOwnWorkbooks()

Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim CMO As Variant
Dim CMOS As Variant
Dim wbDest As Workbook
Dim RAF As Workbook
Set RAF = ThisWorkbook
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell))

CMOS = Array("Element Care", "CCACG EAST", "SCMO", "CCACG WEST", "Uphams Corner Hlth Cent", "CCC-Boston", "Vinfen", "Behavioral Hlth Ntwrk", _
      "CommH Link Worc", "Long Term Care CMO", "Advocates, Inc", "CCC-Springfield", "BU Geriatric Service", "Lynn Comm HC", "CCA-BHI", "BIDJP Subacute", _
      "CCC-Lawrence", "CCC-Framingham", "East Boston Neighborhoo", "BosHC 4 Homeless", "Bay Cove Hmn Srvces", "Mailhoit, Carrie", "Brightwood Hlth Ctr-Bay", _
      "Romero, Michele", "Isaacs, Cindy", "McCoy, Viola", "ADRC of Greater North Shore", "Geller, Marian")

```
For Each CMO In CMOS

On Error Resume Next

RAF.Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Sheets("MASTER Summary").Select
Range("F12").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_Query_from_ProdServerP052").Range.AutoFilter _
    Field:=11, Criteria1:=CMO
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Set wbDest = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveSheet.Cells.Select
Selection.ColumnWidth = 8.29
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Selection.ColumnWidth = 78.71
Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "Summary"
Range("C24").Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng, , xlYes).Name = _
    "Table1"
Range("Table1[#All]").Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight13"
RAF.Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Sheets("MASTER Detail").Select
Range("A2").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_Query_from_ProdServerP054").Range.AutoFilter _
    Field:=7, Criteria1:=CMO
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
wbDest.Activate
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Cells.Select
Selection.ColumnWidth = 34.29
Selection.ColumnWidth = 50.71
Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
wbDest.Sheets("Sheet2").Select
wbDest.Sheets("Sheet2").Name = "Detail"
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng, , xlYes).Name = _
          "Table2"
Range("Table2[#All]").Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight13"
Range("A13").Select
wbDest.Sheets("Summary").Select
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wbDest.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & _
CMO & " " & Format(Date, "mmm_dd_yyyy")
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
wbDest.Close
Next CMO
```

End Sub

Comment: i would like to update the CMOs varable based on a range in worksheet in the same file called "CMO list".